# Error XML5633 on IE

Tags: php, html, xml

Hi all I have a site where I make a call to a server with curl with an xml and retrieve resul
In Firefox and Chrome works fine but in Internet Explorer 9 return me this error on the close tag

> `</head>`

ERROR:

> XML 5633: The name of the end tag does not match the name of the
>   corresponding start tag.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://myurl/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://myurl/css/backend/jquery-ui-1.9.1.css"  rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://myurl/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
//rest of code
```

The XML request is (In other browser works fine the request the parameters are ok):

```
$xml_data ="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<BOOKING type='HA' lang='it-IT' returnURLNeed='no' returnURL='http://' AGENTCODE='XXX' AGENTPASSWORD='YYY' AVAILABLE_HOTELS_ONLY='NO' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='http://link/Hrequest.xsd'>
    <DATA COUNTRY_CODE='".$nation_code."' CITY_CODE='".$city_code."'>
<ROOMS_DATA ".$room."/>
<DATE_DATA CHECK_IN_DATE='".$date_start."' CHECK_OUT_DATE='".$date_end."'/>
<OPTIONAL_DATA ".$rating." NeedReductionAmount='NO' NeedHotelMessages='NO' NeedFreeNightDetails='NO' SortingOrder='Low'/>
<ADDITIONAL_DATA PICTURE_NEED='YES' AMENITY_NEED='NO' HOTEL_ADDRESS_NEED='NO' TELEPHONE_NO_NEED='NO' FAX_NO_NEED='NO' EMAIL_NEED='NO' HotelDescription='YES' HotelCity='YES' HotelProperties='YES' HotelArrivalPointOther='NO' HotelArrivalPoint='NO' GeoCodes='YES' Location='YES' CityArea='YES' EnglishTextNeed='NO'/>".$multirating."
    </DATA>
</BOOKING>";
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try

change:

```
<DATA COUNTRY_CODE='".$nation_code."' CITY_CODE='".$city_code."'>
```

To:

```
<DATA COUNTRY_CODE=".$nation_code." CITY_CODE=".$city_code.">
```

change:

```
<DATE_DATA CHECK_IN_DATE='".$date_start."' CHECK_OUT_DATE='".$date_end."'/>
```

To:

```
<DATE_DATA CHECK_IN_DATE=".$date_start." CHECK_OUT_DATE=".$date_end."/>
```

Edit 1:

Close tags explicitely like `</DATE_DATA>`

Edit 2:

increase or decrease jquery  version

Edit 3:

Disable IE add-ons

Comment: Isn't that problem, because the request need ''. If I edit this the request doesn't work! Not this the problem